# How do I get two variables inside a function in map()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this function:

```py
import concurrent.futures

def function_abc(a,b):
    #do something
```

I call this function with this:

```py
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(function_abc, a, b)
```

But this does not work.

If I remove the argument "b":

```py
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(function_abc, a)
```

It works anyway. But I don't get the additional argument inside of this function.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Has your question been answered? If so, please mark the solution as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

Pass your arguments as separate iterables, one for `a` and another for `b`:

```py
In [2]: with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as ex:
   ...:     m = ex.map(pow, (2, 2, 2, 2), (2, 3, 4, 5))
   ...:
   ...: for item in m:
   ...:     print(item)
   ...:
4
8
16
32
```

To be more explicit:

```py
ex.map(func_of_a_and_b, (a1, a2, a3, a4, ...), (b1, b2, b3, b4, ...))
```

Comment: That seems to be what they're already doing, and what they claim "does not work".

Comment: OP has not indicated the type of `a` and `b`. It seems to me as if they are applying a single argument `a` and `b`, not iterables of all `a` args and all `b` args.

Comment: Maybe. But they say with just `a` "It works anyway", so maybe there actually is some other earlier issue. They're soooo good at providing details. I'd say someone should request that they show their `a` and `b`, make it an mre, and say what "does not work" means. Maybe someone interested in posting an answer :-P

Answer (score -2):

You can pass in a list of tuples instead. Tuples are defined as (a, b, c...) and cannot be modified, but you can access them the same as lists (with an index, reverse index, slicing).

So basically nested lists but `python somelist = [sometuple, sometuple, sometuple]`

For example:

```py
## Lets say this function multiplies a and b
# This is a compact and fast way
def function_abc(tup):
    return tup[0]*tup[1]

## This makes it possible to modify the variables (not the tuple) and a bit nicer for more complicated code
## This also has lists
def function_abc(tup):
    a = tup[0]
    b = tup[1]

    a = a/2
    #tup[0] = tup[0]/2  <- Will show error as tuples are immutable    

    return a*b


def combine(a, b):
    if len(a) != len(b):
        print("Wrong lengths!")

    l = []
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        l.append((a[i], b[i]))

    return l

## In map:

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [10, 9, 8]

results = list(map(function_abc, combine(a, b))) # Should work
print(results)
```

Note that you will need a combine function to combine the 2 lists into a list of tuples

EDIT: Fixed code with combine function. What was I thinking?

Comment: Note: Unlike the previous code, I actually checked this code with an interpreter.

Comment: That's not `executor.map`. And you seem to be reimplementing `zip`. Why?

Comment: Sorry I don't know about zip, and executor.map is extremely similar to map (According to the docs). Also I commonly accidentally remake built in functions

Comment: Also, you don't even need that, [`map` does work fine with multiple iterables](https://tio.run/##TYxBCsIwEEX3c4q/TGQW2m6q4EmkSFJTDNQ0TCYLTx9L6cK3@4/Py199r6kfsrT2CjPmmiaNa3o6PxnH8PZG2JCgVRIcTvBEDnc8LoyO0Y/k93VmXBnDSCSh1EXLZpdY1HxcNv9Zxt61lCUmNcfbtvYD). As should their `executor.map`.